# Convert Days into Weeks then Months and then Years with Formulas

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula

The below formula converts the timestamp into Day(s) ago. But I want to convert this into week(s) ago, month(s) ago and year(s) ago. How can I modify this formula

```
=IFERROR( ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),DATEDIF(VLOOKUP(A3:A,Backend!A2:U,18,FALSE),TODAY(),"D")&if(DATEDIF(VLOOKUP(A3:A,Backend!A2:U,18,FALSE),TODAY(),"D")=1," Day"," Days"),)),)
```

The original format looks like this `7/27/2021 16:11:14`in the **Backend** Sheet **R** Column

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are two different applications and use different formulas. Please delete the irrelevant tag/s.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes Actually The tags were suggested by the Stackoverflow itself when I was typing it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the keep the output as number and add the unit with display format `[=1]0" day"; 0" days"`

**Day:**

```
=IFERROR( ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),DATEDIF(VLOOKUP(A3:A,Backend!A2:U,18,FALSE),TODAY(),"D"),)),)
```

**Month:**

```
=IFERROR( ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),DATEDIF(VLOOKUP(A3:A,Backend!A2:U,18,FALSE),TODAY(),"M"),)),)
```

**Year:**

```
=IFERROR( ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),DATEDIF(VLOOKUP(A3:A,Backend!A2:U,18,FALSE),TODAY(),"Y"),)),)
```

**Week:**
(You may want to do rounding yourself)

```
=IFERROR( ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),DATEDIF(VLOOKUP(A3:A,Backend!A2:U,18,FALSE),TODAY(),"D")/7,)),)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is I didn't understand how to`[=1]0" day"; 0"` into the formula and I want all day/s,week/s, Month/s,Year/s in one single line, can you please help me to modify this?